# query on Neo4j in java applications

Tags: neo4j

I'm working with Neo4j in java application. How do I count all nodes in a database and print on the screen? Can anyone help me?

```
    package pesquisaBanco;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
//import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class pesquisar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/Users/Jessica/neo4j");
        Transaction transaction;
        transaction = graphDb.beginTx();

        //QUERY HERE!

        transaction.success();
        transaction.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with Cypher [COUNT aggregation function](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#_count):
`MATCH n RETURN count(n) AS count`.

The alias defined by `AS` is just there to make it easier with [`columnAs`](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.2/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionResult.html#columnAs(java.lang.String)) below.

Please note that the best practice is to wrap the transaction in a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block, such as:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
try (Transaction transaction= graphDb.beginTx();
     ResourceIterator<Long> results = engine.execute("MATCH n RETURN count(n) AS count").columnAs("count")) {

   System.out.println(results.next());
   transaction.success();
}
```